# Why was my question closed while it looks like similar questions are still open?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, closed-questions

Recently, my question regarding a good introductory book on mathematical risk theory was [closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290071/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-mathematical-risk-theory) because it was deemed off-topic and not research-level mathematics.

However, I think that multiple similar questions were not closed and garnered loads of responses. Those include:

1. "Good books in Modular Representation Theory" ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55983/good-books-in-modular-representation-theory?rq=1))
2. "Good books on theory of distributions" ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20314/good-books-on-theory-of-distributions?rq=1))
3. "A good book of functional analysis" ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72419/a-good-book-of-functional-analysis?rq=1))

It seems to me these questions are similar to mine. I don't understand that my question was closed while these other questions I just mentioned look rather similar to me.

Furthermore, I think my question *is* about research-level mathematics. The theory of risk measures is a pretty advanced and a difficult topic. So it's not like I'm asking for a good introductory book on, say, calculus.

Comment: Fair enough, but one point is that each one of those is a link to a pretty old question, when questions were often received differently from how they probably would be today.

Comment: I think part of the poor reception is that crossposts are frowned upon. You posted both questions just a day apart, so there is no reason to think your question would go unanswered on MSE (and it was). Personally I find the question a valid one.

Comment: I'd say questions for introductory books are not normally on-topic on MO -- what may be possible though is to ask for a good textbook if you teach a particular course.

Comment: Notice also that the people who asked the questions 1.-3. to which you linked are rather low-reputation users.

Comment: "But officer, what about all those other murders you haven't caught? Why do you must punish me?" (only that comparing murder to posting on MO is pretty absurd, but you get my hyperbole and a half, I hope.)

Comment: What irritates me quite a bit is that I am ready to bet 100 bucks against 1 that at least 4 out of 5 people didn't bother to find out an answer before voting to close, so their judgement of the level of the question can hardly be taken more seriously than the proverbial public opinion on the length of the emperor's nose.  IMO the question is completely legitimate by itself, though, indeed, cross-posting without a good reason is usually frowned upon.